# Generating / patching an XML file with a CMake variable

Tags: xml, cmake

In my CMake-based project I have some XML files used to generate code (using the typical `add_custom_command` & `add_custom_target` pattern).

This XML file includes other files as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <definition
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../MyComponent/schema.xsd">
    <include href="../../../MyComponent/another.xml" />
</definition>
```

Now I want to make `../../../MyComponent` dependent on a CMake variable. What would definitely would work is to write a generator that takes an XML template and replaces the paths with the content of a CMake variable using, here also, the `add_custom_command` & `add_custom_target` pattern.

Is there a solution that would make use of simple CMake and/or XML mechanisms to patch or generate the correct path?

Comment: If you don't need this XML outside your CMake build environment, then you could add the `${...}` variable syntax to your XML file and use [`configure_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/configure_file.html) to generate the "configured" version to e.g. your binary output directory.

Comment: This is a very good hint, thanks! I didn't know this CMake command. Feel free to formulate it as an answer I'd elect as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

I've used the following technique to e.g. generate user project setting XML files for CMake generated VS environments (see e.g. [this](http://cmake.limitpoint.com/setting-the-visual-studio-debugger-path-using-cmake/) blog post by Jim Butler).

In your case I would do:

**some.xml.in**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <definition
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="${_my_xml_root_path}/schema.xsd">
    <include href="${_my_xml_root_path}/another.xml" />
</definition>
```

And in your `CMakeLists.txt` something like (depending on the path you want to inject):

```
get_filename_component(_my_xml_root_path "../../../MyComponent" ABSOLUTE)
set(_some_xml_path "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/some.xml")
configure_file("some.xml.in" "${_some_xml_path}")
```

Then you can use `${_some_xml_path}` later to give as an input file to some other build step.