# Use cmake variable in xsd file

Tags: xsd, cmake

I have an XML Schema (xsd) file that includes another xsd file as follows:

```
  <xs:include schemaLocation="../xmlschema/DataPrimitives.xsd"/>
```

What should I do to replace "../xmlschema" by a cmake variable? In other words, I would like to end up with something like that:

```
  <xs:include schemaLocation="..${my_schema_path}/DataPrimitives.xsd"/>
```

Thank you

Comment: Use [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html).

Comment: @Biffen Thank you. Will this also work in out of source builds?

Comment: Yes, just keep track of where you put the generated file.

Comment: @Biffen Thanks, actually got it to work by doing something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437695/generating-patching-an-xml-file-with-a-cmake-variable